# VBA-IE: Click on HTML element with only a href attribute

Tags: excel, ie-automation, vba

I need to go to the next page by clicking "Anmelden".
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WknJy.png)

This elements are described in html code as:

```
<nav id="main-menu" role="navigation">

          <a href="https://csp.stocko-contact.com/portal/">Startseite</a>
          <a href="https://csp.stocko-contact.com/portal/authenticate.php">Anmelden</a>  </nav>
```

In my VBA code I try to pick this links with code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim l As Object
Dim link As HTMLAnchorElement
```

(...)

```
For Each l In IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    If l.href = "https://csp.stocko-contact.com/portal/authenticate.php" Then
    l.Click
    End If
Exit For
Next
```

I work with IE8. Any advice? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're searching the href for a *specific* URL, why not just `IE.Navigate "https://csp.stocko-contact.com/portal/authenticate.php"`?

Comment: Why not, instead of `l.Click`, put in `IE.navigate l.href`?

Comment: Your `Exit For` should be inside the `If` block after `l.Click`: as it stands your loop will always exit after the first link is checked.

Comment: You were right, IE.Navigate was the simplest solution. Thank you for your comment.